# Pandas plot gives mismatched x-axis with secondary_y=True

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot two Pandas Series with matching indexes on the same plot (one as a line and the other as bars) using the df.plot() syntax. But when I add the bar plot the line plot axis ends up wrong. Why isn't this working?

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
df = pd.Series({0.142:5,0.3643:1,0.5523:2})
df.plot(use_index=True)

df.plot(kind='bar',secondary_y=True,color='b',use_index=True)
```

Comment: Since you explicitely ask "what am I doing wrong?"  - You didn't google for "pandas line and bar plot" or similar.

Comment: My question is why doesn't my code work, not how can I make a line-bar plot in Python. I am able to get what I want using `ax2 = ax1.twinx()` `ax1.plot(df.index,df)`, but I want to understand how to use the Pandas .plot method since it's quicker and more concise.

Comment: The reason your code doesn't work is that pandas bar plots are categorical plots, while line plots are numeric plots. The bar labelled "0.5523" is really at position 2 on the numeric scale.

Comment: Hmm okay. That seems like weird behavior since the Series index itself is numeric, and matplotlib bar plots which I assumed Pandas would be wrapping do use a numeric x-axis by default (https://www.screencast.com/t/Eh9sQSfe). I do understand the problem now though, thanks!

Comment: Well, yes, that's why all the answers to this question say that one should use a matplotlib plot instead.